# How to paint over safe area in jetpack compose?

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose

I am trying to paint that dark blue area with the gradient as well.

[image].

I am basically looking for `ignoreSafeArea` (iOS SwiftUI)

[image]

Equivalent for Jetpack Compose. I could try painting that bar the same shade of blue I used for my gradient but I don't think that is the best solution.

I have tried changing the `appBar` color but the result is not what I am looking for.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This bar is the Android [Status Bar](https://material.io/design/platform-guidance/android-bars.html#status-bar).
To change its color in Jetpack Compose you can use the Google [Accompanist](https://google.github.io/accompanist/) library, specifically the [System UI Controller](https://google.github.io/accompanist/systemuicontroller/).

> System UI Controller provides easy-to-use utilities for updating the System UI bar colors within Jetpack Compose.

Specifically the `setSystemBarsColor` or `setStatusBarColor` functions.

```kotlin
systemUiController.setStatusBarsColor(
    color = Color.Transparent, //set your color here
    darkIcons = true
)
```

Then, to draw under the status bar area you can use the [`WindowCompat`](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/core/view/WindowCompat) in your `MainActivity`

```kotlin
WindowCompat.setDecorFitsSystemWindows(window, false)

setContent {
    MyApp(
      ...
    )
}
```

To prevent content (like AppBar) from going under system icons I used [Inset-aware layouts](https://google.github.io/accompanist/insets/#inset-aware-layouts-insets-ui) by setting a Box with top padding passed from Accompanist Scaffold.

```kotlin
Box(Modifier.padding(top = contentPadding.calculateTopPadding())) {
   // my app content
}
```

Comment: Where is contentPadding?

Comment: There is now `safeDrawingPadding()` and `safeContentPadding()`.